# How to compute formula by only inputting number of days

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX4DQ.png)

So I am creating a Payroll Management System using C# in visual studio 2019. What I want to happen with my program is I will input a number of days for example '3' in the "regular ot" textbox (please refer to the image posted above) and it will compute the regular ot rate for 3 days. This is the formula to calculate the regular ot (basic rate/26)/8.
I've already tried this

```
regOT = ((Convert.ToInt32(tb_basicrate.Text) / 26) / 8);
```

but I don't know what to do next. I hope someone will help

Comment: What do you intend to use that number for? Also, know that integer division gives another integer, so for instance `10/3` gives 3, not 3.333333, so dividing an integer by 26, and then by 8, is *probably* not what you want to do, but only you can tell.

Comment: Are you asking us what your requirements are? Cause that's useless, we have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: Try dividing by `26.0` and `8.0`.

Comment: should I change it to double variable?

Comment: my goal is to only input number of days in the textbox and it will compute the regular ot rate

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [this section about adding images to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images). This is much preferred over a simple link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

guys I managed to solve it :) I just included the regular ot in the equation so now the rate will be multiplied by the number of days that the user will enter. feels good to solve it man :)

```
regOT = (Convert.ToInt32(tb_basicrate.Text) / 26) / 8 * (Convert.ToInt32(tb_regularot.Text));
```